# Focusing on an external java window? WINDOWS

Tags: java, windows, vbscript

I'm using a robot to click on a certain point on the screen. I just need a way for the robot to bring the desired window to focus. Now here's where the real problem lies, the window is a Java window, but not one I made. I used a VBscript to focus on Firefox earlier, but I'm not sure what to do. When I mouse over the icon on my toolbar, it says the windows name is "BitMinter Client v1.4.2" but in Task Manager it calls the process "Java(TM) Platform SE binary (32 bit)?

How do I focus in on the window?

Having the robot input ALT+TAB won't work because the window isn't second on my ALT+TAB list.

Answer (score 0):

AppActivate looks for matching Window's titles.

Use spy++ (Windows SDK and most MS development tools) to get the window title.

You mention firefox so I don't know what type of Window you are referring to. In IE most web page elements (and for that matter very many other Window's things) haven't been Windows for decades. I don't know how firefox or java are implemented.

Windows basic architecture is windows (such as edit controls/buttons) inside other windows (a pane) inside a top level window (ie notepad) inside the desktop window.

To take notepad. There is a main window, menu bar, statusbar window, edit control window. Each of them has a title and class. This is notepad's title and class.

```
Untitled - Notepad  Notepad 
    «No Window Text 0»  Edit    
    «No Window Text 0»  msctls_statusbar32
```